# Custom Button on Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, page-layout, button

I created a custom button Send Email in Lightning Experience. The problem is that button in visible in feed section layout, but I want to put it in the upper right corner of page layouts near Edit, Clone, Delete ecc....

How Can I do that? Thanks

I add an image that explain the situation.

[image]

EDIT:
I would like to explain you better my problem.

I have created three custom quick action:
[image]

I have added them to the case page Layout as you can see

[image]

I would like to understand the reason why I don’t see these three custom action in the Page Layout in the section in the top right

[image]

Comment: The button on the detail side are they part of a custom component ? If so check if the custom component implements lightning:quickactionwithoutheader component. I recently looked at another post where this quickactionwithoutheader was messing up all the actions on the hightlight section. If this is not it then you may have to paste 2 things 1) lightning app builder for this object to see if this is the same pagelayout you are editing 2) Record type section to see if  you have selected the buttons to be part of the record type ( assuming there are record types for this object)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please refer to this:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=0

> In Lightning Experience, actions display in the Global Actions menu in
> the header, on related lists, on list view items, and in several
> places on a record page. Where they appear on a record page **depends on
> the action’s type**.
>
> [...]
> The page-level action menu in the record’s highlights panel (1) contains:
> [...] Global and object-specific quick actions, except for those related to creating tasks, creating events, and logging calls. [...]
>
> The Activity tab (2) contains **Create a Record quick actions that point to the Event and Task objects**. It also contains Log A Call actions and **Send Email actions**.

It's a built-in Lightning page behaviour. If you have a Quick Action that creates an Activity or sends an E-mail, it winds up in that tab instead of the button area. They just don't give you any choice in the matter.

Answer (score 3):

1) What you are pointing to is called as actions in the highlights section.

2) what you see there is a action not a button. You have to create a lightning action and if you want to override the actions you see in the highlight section, you will have to modify the pagelayout to include the action.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_migration_customization/units/lex_migration_customization_actions

[image]

If you edit the pagelayout related to an user you will be able to add/remove actions from the Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience Actions section.( You will see an option to override the actions and remove the buttons that you do not want to part of the layout)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an action for the object and then add it to the page layout in the Salesforce1 & Lightning Actions section.[image]

Comment: I did it, but the problem still remains the same

Comment: @L.benedettini Did this get resolved?  Sometimes there is a caching delay if you haven't turned that off in your sandbox.  May take a few refreshes for your changes to be reflected.