# Lightning Component Button Showing in Related List - Move to Page-Level Action Menu

Tags: lightning-aura-components, button

This question has a few flavors out there. This is NOT a duplicate of the  [closest question I can find](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/194784/custom-button-on-lightning-experience) since the accepted answer does not apply to my use case.

I am trying implement a custom button for Cases called "Take Ownership" that assigns the Case to the current user. I have that process working, and I have a button:

```
<aura:component controller="AuraButtonHelper" implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="case" type="Case"/>
    <ui:button aura:id="mybtn" class="slds-button slds-button--brand" label="TEST Take Ownership" press="{!c.onclick}"  />
</aura:component>
```

This button does NOT create a Task, Event, or Phone Call. This is attached to a Custom Action.

[image: Custom Action Screenshot]

My button is on the Layout:

[image]

And my button appears in the related list:
[image]

As noted in [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=0), the area at the top right ("page-level action menu") will contain:

> Global and object-specific quick actions, except for those actions related to creating tasks, creating events, and logging calls

here's where my question differs from the prior question. As far as I can tell, my button *is* a global quick action (implements `force:lightningQuickAction` and tagged `access="global"`).

[Feed Tracking](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/230816/lightning-component-as-a-button) is off for Cases and I checked the [platformActionList](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226745/custom-button-not-showing-in-page-level-action-menu-in-lightning) in the layout metadata.

I believe I am doing what I should to get the button to show up in the page-level action menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

idk know weather you observed or not in doc which u attached in question [quick action doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=0),

you created a action with lightning component action type on case object, some objects Quick action displayed based on feed tracking, like `case,user profile,work orders` for these objects actions displayed in different places then you expected area ,i think your org is feed enabled on case object.

> NOTE Actions on user profiles, cases, and work orders can appear in a different way than on other records.
>   Actions on the user profile page come from the Quick Actions in the Salesforce Classic Publisher section of the global publisher layout. Only standard Chatter actions appear on the user profile page, regardless of which actions are assigned to the User Page Layout or the global publisher layout.
>   When feed tracking is enabled for cases or work orders, the page-level action menu on those records contains only custom buttons and supported standard buttons. Quick actions appear on the Chatter tab.

Comment: Thank you, Feed Tracking is disabled for Cases. I have edited my original post to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you, I reviewed this again. I had gone to the Case Feed page and thought I disabled it. The UI can be wonky, so disabling Case Feed didn't "take".